# Laravel 8 is not working correctly, error "file_put_contents"

Tags: laravel

I'm having some weird problem with Laravel 8.

I installed the framework and started working with it, but when I try to edit / delete some controller, my Ubuntu asks for a password.

Another problem. My controller displays records on a page with `paginate(15)` pagination, but instead of the usual numbers, I get the Previous & Next direction, and when I try to change something in the html template, I get an error `file_put_contents(/var/www/storage/framework/views/c6d615eb91fe3a0edd449165e94d034703bbb84d.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied`  and this problem can only be cured by clearing the cache, but this should not be the case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set up file permissions for Laravel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30639174/how-to-set-up-file-permissions-for-laravel)

Comment: I have no problems with storage

Comment: Sounds like a permission problem where the user which is used to install Laravel is different from the one that runs the webserver. Check which user is running the webserver and which one created the Laravel project

Comment: So this error says:`file_put_contents(/var/www/storage...` maybe you have permission problem.

Answer (score 0):

Error #1: Your user does not have write permissions for those files/directories. Did you use `sudo` while installing or copying anything? Do you have these files outside of your home directory? (`/home/username/`)

Error #2: Your webserver (nginx, apache, etc.) probably does not have access to the application's /storage/ directory.

Answer (score 0):

1. SSH into the server.
2. Navigate to the projects root folder.
3. Run the following commands to make the directories writable:

```
    sudo chmod -R gu+w storage/
    sudo chmod -R guo+w storage/
    sudo chmod -R gu+w bootstrap/cache/
    sudo chmod -R guo+w bootstrap/cache/
```